# A word for someone who knows others' intentions

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

perceptive? intuitive? But a noun. Specifically referring to the psychology of those around her. She knows of others' intentions from paying attention, listening and she has an excellent gauge for what they would do in certain situations. Other characters are conquerors, loyalists, counselors, students, etc. She can read people well. She is a knower, a ____.

Comment: Maybe "perceiver".... but hopefully someone can up with something better...

Comment: a ***mind-reader***, perhaps?

Comment: @Hellion Nah, that's not the right word.

Comment: She's a people reader, see [Lisa Mitchell](https://www.facebook.com/powerbodylanguage)

Comment: _Mentalist_? _Sherlock_?

Comment: She is an empath.  If you google empath, you will get a lot of hits, but the entries referring to the Real World seem very fluffy to me.   In the Star Trek universe, Betazoids were empaths.  Anyone wants to run with this, be my guest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***People-reader*** (per Gypsy Spellweaver).  ([Blog on people reading.](http://smithlahrman.blogspot.com/2010/03/reading-people.html))

Ironically, @Gypsy Spellweaver has offered in the comments the only viable answer that doesn't involve some supernatural ability. The OP has told us where the ability comes from -- **paying attention** and **listening** -- not clairvoyance.

"She can read people well. She is a knower, a *people-reader*."

Answer (score -1):

**Percipient** can be used as a noun as well as an adjective. See the [Online Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/percipient) which gives the definition

*(especially in philosophy or with reference to psychic phenomena) a person who is able to perceive things.*

This might well serve your purpose.

Comment: I am surprised Ericka has accepted this.  The person described in the question knows others from **paying attention** and **listening** not from some psychic, supernatural clairvoyance.

Comment: @thomj1332 Perhaps this answer, despite the overtones, fits the OP's use case better.

Comment: I'd just never heard of percipient before. The challenge for me was finding a noun to fit what I needed. Either percipient or empath or people-reader would work. Thanks everybody!

Comment: @thomj1332 Look at the definition, thom. It says in reference to either psychic phenomena _or_ philosophy. I take it that the philosophy definition has no connection with the spooky woo-woo stuff.

Comment: Good point.  I will upvote yours answer.